# Confusions about implementing a SearchView with online suggestions

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-search

I am implementing a SearchView on ActionBar with ActionBarSherlock. I went through the documentation on this topic: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html
but I am confused:

(1) It seems the framework pushes you to use ContentProvider for suggestions and SearchView retrieves the suggestions by calling the `ContentProvider.query()` method. However, I don't think I can use this framework because I will get my suggestions from a server. That is, I will provide a keyword to call an api, after the data is fetched, a callback function will be called. So it is async so that the query() method won't work. Can I get rid of the ContentProvider to implement the suggestions?

(2) My suggestion items should be customized. There will be a CheckBox in each item. So I think I should use a customized adapter. I only found a method `setSuggestionAdapter()` in SearchView which only receives CursorAdapter. From my knowledge, CursorAdapter is used for database query. However there is no database concept in my case.

(3) It seems you have to bind your SearchView to an Activity. Is it really necessary or can we bind it to a Fragment instead?

Any suggestions for this ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ad 1) it will use default drop-down list so you can have customized items with check boxes, ad 2) yes, setSuggestionAdapter() will work, just use it with MatrixCursor, ad 3) que? what do you mean?

Comment: btw you could use ContentProvider as well but you cannot change the drop down used by default by SearchView

Comment: so what does the binding mean here?

Comment: @pskink I have a handler function for the search. In the documentation  it says you should make an activity searchable. But it's meaningless to make an Activity searchable in my case. So I am thinking if we can make an Fragment searchable or nothing.

Comment: just set a SearchView as a custom view in a ActionBar, dont need to bind to anything

Comment: and what, did it work?

Comment: @pskink Thanks. I am trying to add a customized drop-down list to the action bar (An RelativeLayout with a search button, a AutoCompleteTextView and a clear button). Right now the UI side is working well (view expansion, drop-down list showing). I think the SearchView in Android framework is designed for the case of searching in database. It may not be a good idea to use it in my case (Display suggestions based on web api calls).

Comment: see my ad 2) you can use a std SerchView with no problem